# Adding form triggers to multiple forms programmatically AppsScript

Tags: google-apps-script, automation, google-forms

Is there a way to add onSubmit trigger to N number of forms in an array using AppScript to send a copy of the form response to people who fill out the form? I am looking for something like:

```
function createForm(fileName, title, description) {

    var form = FormApp.create(fileName).setTitle(title).setDescription(description);
    form.sendACopyOfTheResponse(); //I am looking for something like this
}

function createForms() {
   . . .
   for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
      createForm(fileName, title, description);
   }
   . . .
}
```

I believe that a way to do this is to add triggers however, this function should create ~10-15 forms and I should be able to programmatically add the trigger to each form.

Comment: You can accomplish what you want with one trigger on the linked spreadsheet.

Comment: how can I programmatically add the trigger to multiple sheets?

Comment: When you used the sheets do you mean spreadsheets or individual sheets/tabs?

Comment: if you mean Sheet as in Class Sheets then there is no issue because multiple form attached to the same spreadsheet all work off of the same trigger and you can determine which form initiated the trigger by using e.range.getSheet() to determine which sheet was written to which correlates directly to a form.  If you mean multiple spreadsheet then the onformsubmit must be created for each spreadsheet.